# Embed facebook video to play with mobile web

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, iframe, video

I used code bellow to embed videos from my facebook page into my Web App.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=XXX" width="720" height="1280" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Simple browser can play them smoothly because all most of desktop browsers have flash player. But when I open them with mobile browsers to view my Web App it require to upgrade/install flash player.

I know the best way to embed video use HTML5 for mobile browser. But I don't know how to embed Facebook's video with HTML5?

Please give your advice to embed Facebook with Video with HTML5.

Comment: Hi, I am trying exactly the same thing? has anyone find a solution ?
cheers